# CheckBox Column in DatagridView built on linq to Entities query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` built on linq to entities. I used Entity Framework to build the Model on a database view. One column is a bool type but the `DataGridView` gives me the text 'true' or 'false'. I want display that information in a checkBox Column. But I can't force `DataGridView` to change it.

```
public partial class view_1    
{

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string PERSON { get; internal set; }

    public bool ACCEPT { get; set; }
}

sEntities context = new sEntities();

var lQuery = from p in context.view_1 select p;

DataGridView1.DataSource = lQuery.ToList();
```

I expect to have a `CheckboxColumn` connected with the ACCEPT field.

Comment: Hi, I found solution my problem (it was on my side). I have Nullable type `bool?`, if I change type on `bool` I get `CheckboxColumn` instead of text 'True' or 'False'. Thanks for help and correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The following code example demonstrates how to use a
>   [DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcheckboxcolumn?view=netframework-4.8) to mark which employees are out of the
>   office. This example is part of a larger example available in the
>   [DataGridViewComboBoxColumn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn?view=netframework-4.8) class overview topic.

```
private void AddOutOfOfficeColumn()
{
    DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn column = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
    {
        column.HeaderText = ColumnName.OutOfOffice.ToString();
        column.Name = ColumnName.OutOfOffice.ToString();
        column.AutoSizeMode = 
            DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
        column.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Standard;
        column.ThreeState = true;
        column.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewCheckBoxCell();
        column.CellTemplate.Style.BackColor = Color.Beige;
    }

    DataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, column);
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcheckboxcolumn?view=netframework-4.8

**Or**

**Binding a datatable to the DataGridView having a bool column.**

1. Add a datatable to code:

   DataTable dtEmp = new DataTable();
   // add column to datatable
   dtEmp.Columns.Add("IsMarried", typeof(bool));
   dtEmp.Columns.Add("EmpID", typeof(int));
   dtEmp.Columns.Add("EmpName", typeof(string));
   dtEmp.Columns.Add("EmpCity", typeof(string));

Here we defined a bool column, IsMarried.

1. Adding data:

   dtEmp.Rows.Add(false, 111, "Devesh", "GZB");
   dtEmp.Rows.Add(false, 222, "ROLI", "KANPUR");
   dtEmp.Rows.Add(true, 333, "Rajesh", "NOIDa");
   dtEmp.Rows.Add(false,444, "NIKHIL", "KANPUR");
2. Binding Grid:

> DataGGridView1.DataSource = dtEmp;

4. Running Code.

We will get the following screen after running the code:

Checkbox automatically added to datagirdview because of Bool column defined in datatables:

[image]

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deveshomar/adding-checkbox-column-in-datagridview-in-C-Sharp-window-forms/